# How can I show a new screen after a button is pressed in a component in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a created a Carousel component **Splash** and at the last view/page of it, I have a TextInput and button.On Press, I want this button to open a new screen with **BottomNav** component where I can do by other stuffs. I just want this Splash as a landing page. But when on running this code I get Splash and BottomNav mounted in same screen.
My Apps.js:

```
    export class App extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <PaperProvider>
              <Splash />
              <BottomNav />
          </PaperProvider>
        )
      }
    }

    export default App
```

Splash.js:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container} onLayout={this._onLayoutDidChange} >
        <Carousel
          style={this.state.size}
          currentPage={0}
          autoplay
          isLooped={false}
          bulletStyle={{borderColor:'#02101a'}}
          bullets
          chosenBulletStyle={{backgroundColor:'#02101a'}}
        >
          <View style={[styles.container, this.state.size]}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>
                  Sanitize Your Hands Properly
                </Text>
                <Animated.View>
                  <Image source={require('../src/sanitizehand.png')} style={styles.img}/>
                </Animated.View>
                <Text  style={styles.subtitle}>
                  Use an alcohol-based hand sanitizer that contains at least 60% alcohol to disinfect your hand at regular basis.
                </Text>
          </View>
          <View style={[styles.container, this.state.size]}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>
                  Practice Social Distancing 
                </Text>
                <Animated.View>
                  <Image source={require('../src/socialdistancing.png')} style={styles.img}/>
                </Animated.View>
                <Text style={styles.subtitle}>
                  Practice social distancing and maintain space between yourself and others to prevent infection and its spread.
                </Text>
          </View>
          <View style={[styles.container, this.state.size]}>
                <TextInput
                    label='Phone No.'
                    value={this.state.text}
                    placeholder='Enter here'
                    onChangeText={text => this.setState({ text })}
                    style={styles.textinput}
                />
                <Button mode="contained" onPress={() => console.warn('Press')} icon='arrow-right'>
                  Register
                </Button>
          </View>
        </Carousel>
      </View>
    );
  }
```

BottomNav.js:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
      <Tab.Navigator>
        <Tab.Screen name="Home" component={Home} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Feeds" component={Feeds} />
        <Tab.Screen name="Global" component={Global} />
        <Tab.Screen name="FAQ" component={Faq} />

      </Tab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: you are directly including splash and bottomNav screen in your App.js, that's the reason why you are getting both screens in one screen. Firstly you need to create a navigation for this screens and than you can initially show splash screen than on by pressing button you can show BottomNavigator, hope this helps.

Comment: This surely will, thanks a lot.